# How to make a button display random answers?

Tags: c++, random, c++-cli

What I want to make is to display a random answer on button click in C++.
I could make the array with char* but I couldn't display it in a textbox. (I'm kinda new to C++)

Thx for the answers.

[Code what I got](http://pastebin.com/rVF2Caqv)

Comment: We need way more context than this.

Comment: C++ does not have the concept of a button click or a textbox. How are these defined, and why can do they not work with `char*`? (Please provide a complete example that you think should work (apart from the problem that you are having with the array of `char*`)).

Comment: Why do you use array of char*? It would be easier for you to use std::vector<std::string>. Is it Windows or linux application? Show us some code.

Comment: plz give more details. are under windows,linux? using windows api or QT? also explain more what does your program do? what are these "answers"?

Comment: We have textBox1 button1, I want to make it so when button1 is pressed, random string is displayed in textBox1 from the array "stuff"
,but I couldn't even set up the array correctly, stand by for some incorrect code.

Comment: This looks like Visual Studio C++ .NET to me.  You would be better off tagging the question appropriately.

Comment: because it is Visual Studio 10 C++ form application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using unicode character format so change this `char*` to `wchar_t*`.

```
wchar_t* answers[7][40] = {L"hello",L"this",L"is",L"an",L"answer",L"randoms",L"stuff"};
```

Comment: wouldn't it be better to use std::string to get rid of this ugly 40?

Comment: @stefan:-yes, was about to update but my damn internet service....

Comment: what I get now is:
'void System::Windows::Forms::Control::Text::set(System::String ^)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'wchar_t *[40]' to 'System::String ^'

Comment: `this->textBox2->Text = gcnew String(answers[r]);`

Comment: it compiles, but I get this when I try it:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The pointer passed in as a String must not be in the bottom 64K of the process's address space.

Comment: refer here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7704/Arrays-in-C-CLI